# Magento Custom Order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

I have a Custom Order Status **RTO** Let us assume if Customer Not available admin make it us RTO it's working fine But after RTO I want to  reduced **Lifetime Sales** amount

```
public function rtoorderAction(){

                $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');


                $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);
                $order->setData('state', 'rto');
                $order->setStatus('rto');
                $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);
                $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
                $order->save(); 
                $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, null);
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('This Order has been RTO Successfully'));
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session') ->addSuccess('Order Updated Successfully'); $this->_redirectReferer();
            }
```

Comment: Lifetime Sales amount - what does it mean?

Comment: In admin panel Dashboard it shows Lifetime Sales amount there i want to reduced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy this model to

`app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Order/Collection.php`

to

`app/code/Local/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Order/Collection.php`

on line `544` add you order order `state` for filter in this code

```
->where('main_table.state NOT IN(?)', array(
                    Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW,
                    Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT,'rto')
                );
```

Comment: it's working but problem is it not amount not reduce on seller end

Comment: i think question was `In admin panel Dashboard it shows Lifetime Sales amount there i want to reduced ` paste related code i will see but that

Comment: Ya i agree now only i got to know this problem sorry for that what code you want

Comment: post new question with `block > model > and view` of life time sales in seller dashboard.

Comment: You know the file i am using webkul marketplace

Comment: i know but i don't know what is code written that and what code he is using to get seller life time sales. do read code and post it so i can help you on that

Comment: $collection->getSelect()
        ->join(array("ccp" => $prefix."sales_flat_order"),"ccp.entity_id = main_table.mageorderid",array("status" => "status"))
        ->join(array("ccp2" => $prefix."sales_flat_order_item"),"ccp2.product_id = main_table.mageproid AND ccp2.order_id = main_table.mageorderid",array("item_id" => "item_id"));
    $this->setCollection($collection); this file or different file

Comment: just post the code where is showing life time sale?

Comment: It's awarded only

Answer (score 1):

Please add these lines to your config.xml

```
<events>
    <sales_order_save_after>
        <observers>
            <yourmodule>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                <method>decreaseLifeTimeSale</method>
            </yourmodule>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_save_after>
</events>
```

After that, create a file named Observer.php inside your custom model model folder.

```
class Yourcompany_Yourmodule_Model_Observer {
    public function decreaseLifeTimeSale(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
       $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    }    
}
```

Inside decreaseLifeTimeSale you can easily get order model and get its current status and make any custom changes you want.

Comment: Can you please give me exact code on this

Comment: It depends your logic of `decreaseLifeTimeSale` - please make more detail so I am able to work it out

Comment: it's one of the order status if customer not available while deliver time so product return to inventory so admin put rto status for that order it wil be available in sales order page

Comment: so that time i want to resduce amount from Lifetime sale

Comment: do you have code for `decreaseLifeTimeSale ` available?

Comment: No i have custom order status code only