# Magento Custom order Reduced Lifetime sale

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

I am using Marketplace Extension in My site. I have a Custom Order Status **RTO** Let us assume if Customer Not available admin make it us RTO it's working fine But after RTO I want to  reduced **Lifetime Sales** amount

```
public function rtoorderAction(){

                $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');


                $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);
                $order->setData('state', 'rto');
                $order->setStatus('rto');
                $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);
                $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
                $order->save(); 
                $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, null);
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('This Order has been RTO Successfully'));
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session') ->addSuccess('Order Updated Successfully'); $this->_redirectReferer();
            }
```

**.phtml**

```
<?php 
$isPartner= Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->isPartner(); 
$helper= Mage::helper('marketplace');
if($isPartner==1){
    $readresult=Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getOrderdetails();
    $getDateDetail = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getDateDetail();
    $cur_symbol=Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
    $userid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
    $total_sale = 0;
    $total_sale_coll = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleperpartner')->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter('mageuserid',array('eq'=>$userid));
    foreach($total_sale_coll as $value) {
        $total_sale = $value->getAmountrecived();
        $total_remain_sale = $value->getAmountremain();
    }
    $total_remain_sale = $getDateDetail['totalamount']-$total_sale;
    ?>
<div class="fieldset wk_mp_fieldset">
            <div class="wk_sales">
                <div class="wk_todaysale wk_sale_css">
                    <span class="wk_todaysale_bg"></span>
                    <span class="wk_sale_color"><label class="wk_sale_label"><?php echo $helper->__(' Today ') ?></label><br/><?php echo  Mage::helper('core')->currency($getDateDetail['day'], true, false)?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="wk_weeksale wk_sale_css">                   
                    <span class="wk_weeksale_bg"></span>
                    <span class="wk_sale_color"><label class="wk_sale_label"><?php echo $helper->__(' Week ') ?></label><br/><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($getDateDetail['week'], true, false); ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="wk_monthsale wk_sale_css">
                    <span class="wk_monthsale_bg"></span>
                    <span class="wk_sale_color"><label class="wk_sale_label"><?php echo $helper->__(' Month ') ?></label></br><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($getDateDetail['month'], true, false); ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wk_sales" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <div class="wk_totalsale wk_total_sale_css">
                    <span><?php echo $helper->__(' Total Payout ') ?> - <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($total_sale, true, false); ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="wk_remainsale wk_total_sale_css">
                    <span><?php echo $helper->__(' Remaining Amount ') ?> - <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($total_remain_sale, true, false); ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="hor-scroll">
                    <div class="wk_dash_chart">
                        <canvas class="example-plot" id="chart2" height="400" width="593"></canvas>
                    </div>                  
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**saleslist.php**

```
<?php

class Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Saleslist extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('marketplace/saleslist');
    }

    public function getProductSalesDetailById($productId){
        $data = array();
        if($productId > 0){
           $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
           $collection->addFieldToFilter('mageproid',array('eq'=>$productId));
            $i=0;
            foreach ($collection as $record) {
                $data[$i]=array(
                            'magequantity'=>$record->getmagequantity(),
                            'actualparterprocost'=>$record->getactualparterprocost()
                        );
                $i++;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }

    public function getCommsionCalculation($order){
        $percent = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_options/percent');
        $lastOrderId=$order->getId();
        $ordercollection=Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
                                        ->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',array('eq'=>$lastOrderId))
                                        ->addFieldToFilter('cpprostatus',array('eq'=>0));
        foreach($ordercollection as $item){
            $actparterprocost = $item->getActualparterprocost();
            $totalamount = $item->getTotalamount();
            $seller_id = $item->getMageproownerid();

            $collectionverifyread = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleperpartner')->getCollection();
            $collectionverifyread->addFieldToFilter('mageuserid',array('eq'=>$seller_id));
            if(count($collectionverifyread)>=1){
                foreach($collectionverifyread as $verifyrow){
                    $totalsale=$verifyrow->getTotalsale()+$totalamount;
                    $totalremain=$verifyrow->getAmountremain()+$actparterprocost;
                    $verifyrow->setTotalsale($totalsale);
                    $verifyrow->setAmountremain($totalremain);
                    $verifyrow->save();
                }
            }
            else{
                $percent = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_options/percent');         
                $collectionf=Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleperpartner');
                $collectionf->setMageuserid($seller_id);
                $collectionf->setTotalsale($totalamount);
                $collectionf->setAmountremain($actparterprocost);
                $collectionf->setCommision($percent);
                $collectionf->save();                       
            }
            if($seller_id){
                $ordercount = 0;
                $feedbackcount = 0;
                $feedcountid = 0;
                $collectionfeed=Mage::getModel('marketplace/feedbackcount')->getCollection()
                                        ->addFieldToFilter('sellerid',array('eq'=>$seller_id));
                foreach ($collectionfeed as $value) {
                    $feedcountid = $value->getFeedcountid();
                    $ordercount = $value->getOrdercount();
                    $feedbackcount = $value->getFeedbackcount();
                }
                $collectionfeed=Mage::getModel('marketplace/feedbackcount')->load($feedcountid);
                $collectionfeed->setBuyerid($order->getCustomerId());
                $collectionfeed->setSellerid($seller_id);
                $collectionfeed->setOrdercount($ordercount+1);
                $collectionfeed->setFeedbackcount($feedbackcount);
                $collectionfeed->save();
            }
            $item->setCpprostatus(1)->save();   
        }
    }

    public function paysellerpayment($order,$sellerid,$trid){
        $lastOrderId=$order->getId();       
        $actparterprocost = 0;
        $totalamount = 0;
        $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
                                ->addFieldToFilter('cpprostatus',array('eq'=>1))
                                ->addFieldToFilter('paidstatus',array('eq'=>0))
                                ->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',$sellerid)
                                ->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',array('eq'=>$lastOrderId));
        foreach ($collection as $row) {
            $actparterprocost = $actparterprocost + $row->getActualparterprocost();
            $totalamount = $totalamount + $row->getTotalamount();
            $seller_id = $row->getMageproownerid();
        }
        if($actparterprocost){      
            $collectionverifyread = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleperpartner')->getCollection();
            $collectionverifyread->addFieldToFilter('mageuserid',array('eq'=>$seller_id));
            if(count($collectionverifyread)>=1){
                foreach($collectionverifyread as $verifyrow){
                    if($verifyrow->getAmountremain() >= $actparterprocost){
                        $totalremain=$verifyrow->getAmountremain()-$actparterprocost;
                    }
                    else{
                        $totalremain=0;
                    }
                    $verifyrow->setAmountremain($totalremain);
                    $verifyrow->save();
                    $totalremain;
                    $amountpaid=$verifyrow->getAmountrecived();
                    $totalrecived=$actparterprocost+$amountpaid;
                    $verifyrow->setAmountpaid($actparterprocost);
                    $verifyrow->setAmountrecived($totalrecived);
                    $verifyrow->setAmountremain($totalremain);
                    $verifyrow->save();
                }
            }
            else{
                $percent = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_options/percent');         
                $collectionf=Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleperpartner');
                $collectionf->setMageuserid($seller_id);
                $collectionf->setTotalsale($totalamount);
                $collectionf->setAmountpaid($actparterprocost);
                $collectionf->setAmountrecived($actparterprocost);
                $collectionf->setAmountremain(0);
                $collectionf->setCommision($percent);
                $collectionf->save();                       
            }

            if($trid){
                $unique_id = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment_transaction')->load($trid)->getTxnId();
            }else{
                $unique_id = $this->checktransid();
            }
            if($unique_id!=''){
                $seller_trans = Mage::getModel('marketplace/sellertransaction')->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('transactionid',array('eq'=>mysqli_real_escape_string($unique_id)));            
                if(count($seller_trans)){
                    foreach ($seller_trans as $value) {
                        $id =$value->getId();
                        if($id){
                            Mage::getModel('marketplace/sellertransaction')->load($id)->delete();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($order->getPayment()){
                    $paymentCode = $order->getPayment()->getMethod();
                    $payment_type=Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
                }else{
                    $payment_type='Manual';
                }
                $currdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $seller_trans = Mage::getModel('marketplace/sellertransaction');
                $seller_trans->setTransactionid($unique_id);
                $seller_trans->setOnlinetrid($trid);
                $seller_trans->setTransactionamount($actparterprocost);
                $seller_trans->setType('Online');
                $seller_trans->setMethod($payment_type);
                $seller_trans->setSellerid($seller_id);
                $seller_trans->setCustomnote('None');
                $seller_trans->setCreatedAt($currdate);
                $transid = $seller_trans->save()->getTransid();
            }

            $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter('cpprostatus',array('eq'=>1))
                            ->addFieldToFilter('paidstatus',array('eq'=>0))
                            ->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',array('eq'=>$lastOrderId))
                            ->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',$sellerid);
            foreach ($collection as $row) {
                $row->setPaidstatus(1);
                $row->setTransid($transid)->save();
                Mage::dispatchEvent('mp_pay_seller',array("transaction_id"=>$transid,"id"=>$lastOrderId,"seller_id"=>$sellerid));
            }
        }

        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsetData('onlinesellertrids');
    }

    public function randString($length, $charset='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789')
    {
        $str = 'tr-';
        $count = strlen($charset);
        while ($length--) {
            $str .= $charset[mt_rand(0, $count-1)];
        }

        return $str;
    }

    public function checktransid(){
        $unique_id=$this->randString(11);
        $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/sellertransaction')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('transactionid',array('eq'=>mysqli_real_escape_string($unique_id)));
        $i=0;
        foreach ($collection as $value) {
                $i++;
        }   
        if($i!=0){
            $this->checktransid();
        }else{
            return $unique_id;
        }       
    }

    public function getProductSalesCalculation($order){
        $percent = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_options/percent');
        $lastOrderId=$order->getId();
        Mage::dispatchEvent('mp_discount_manager',array("order"=>$order));
        $discountDetails = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('salelistdata');
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item){
            $item_data = $item->getData();
            $attrselection = unserialize($item_data['product_options']);
            $bundle_selection_attributes = unserialize($attrselection['bundle_selection_attributes']);
            if(!$bundle_selection_attributes['option_id']){         
                $temp=$item->getProductOptions();
                if (array_key_exists('seller_id', $temp['info_buyRequest'])) {
                    $seller_id= $temp['info_buyRequest']['seller_id'];
                }
                else {
                    $seller_id='';
                }   
                $currentCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
                $baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();     
                $allowedCurrencies = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getConfigAllowCurrencies(); 
                $rates = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getCurrencyRates($baseCurrencyCode, array_values($allowedCurrencies));
                if(!$rates[$currentCurrencyCode]){
                    $rates[$currentCurrencyCode] = 1;
                }
                if($discountDetails[$item->getProductId()]) 
                    $price = $discountDetails[$item->getProductId()]['price']/$rates[$currentCurrencyCode];
                else
                    $price = $item->getPrice()/$rates[$currentCurrencyCode];
                if($seller_id==''){
                    $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection();
                    $collection_product->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$item->getProductId()));
                    foreach($collection_product as $selid){
                        $seller_id=$selid->getuserid();
                    }
                }
                if($seller_id==''){$seller_id=0;}       
                $collection1 = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleperpartner')->getCollection();
                $collection1->addFieldToFilter('mageuserid',array('eq'=>$seller_id));
                $taxamount=$item_data['tax_amount'];
                $qty=$item->getQtyOrdered();
                $totalamount=$qty*$price;

                if(count($collection1)!=0){
                    foreach($collection1 as $rowdatasale) {
                        $commision=($totalamount*$rowdatasale->getcommision())/100;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    $commision=($totalamount*$percent)/100;
                }   

                $wholedata['id'] = $item->getProductId();
                Mage::dispatchEvent('mp_advance_commission', $wholedata);
                $advancecommission = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('commission');
                if($advancecommission!=''){
                    $percent=$advancecommission;
                    $commType = Mage::getStoreConfig('mpadvancecommission/mpadvancecommission_options/commissiontype');
                    if($commType=='fixed')
                    {
                        $commision=$percent;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $commision=($totalamount*$advancecommission)/100;
                    }     
                    if($commision>$totalamount){ $commission= $totalamount*(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_options/percent'))/100; }
                }           

                $actparterprocost=$totalamount-$commision;
                $collectionsave=Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist');
                $collectionsave->setmageproid($item->getProductId());
                $collectionsave->setmageorderid($lastOrderId);
                $collectionsave->setmagerealorderid($order->getIncrementId());
                $collectionsave->setmagequantity($qty);
                $collectionsave->setmageproownerid($seller_id);
                $collectionsave->setcpprostatus(0);
                $collectionsave->setmagebuyerid(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId());
                $collectionsave->setmageproprice($price);
                $collectionsave->setmageproname($item->getName());
                if($totalamount!=0){
                $collectionsave->settotalamount($totalamount);
                }
                else{
                $collectionsave->settotalamount($price);
                }
                $collectionsave->setTotaltax($taxamount);
                if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_options/taxmanage')){
                    $actparterprocost=$actparterprocost+$taxamount;
                }               
                $collectionsave->settotalcommision($commision);
                $collectionsave->setactualparterprocost($actparterprocost);
                $collectionsave->setcleared_at(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                $collectionsave->save();
                $qty='';
            }
        }
    }

    public function getSalesdetail($mageproid){
        $data = array(
                'quantitysoldconfirmed'=>0,
                'quantitysoldpending'=>0,
                'amountearned'=>0,
                'clearedat'=>0,
                'quantitysold'=>0,
                );
        $sum=0;
        $arr=array();
        $quantity = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('mageproid',array('eq'=>$mageproid));

       foreach($quantity as $rec){
         $status=$rec->getCpprostatus();
         $data['quantitysold']=$data['quantitysold']+$rec->getMagequantity();
         if($status==1){
            $data['quantitysoldconfirmed']=$data['quantitysoldconfirmed']+$rec->getMagequantity();
         }else{
            $data['quantitysoldpending']=$data['quantitysoldpending']+$rec->getMagequantity();
         }
       }

        $amountearned = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('cpprostatus',array('eq'=>1));
        $amountearned->getSelect()->where('mageproid ='.$mageproid);
        foreach($amountearned as $rec) {
        $data['amountearned']=$data['amountearned']+$rec->getactualparterprocost();
        $arr[]=$rec->getClearedAt();
        }
        $data['clearedat']=$arr;
        return $data;
    }
    public function createdAt($mageproid){
        $arr=array();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('eq' => $mageproid));
        foreach($collection as $rec) {
        $arr[]=$rec->getCreatedAt();
        }
        return $arr;
    }
    public function getDateDetail(){ 
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); 
        $cidvar = $session->getId();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',array('eq'=>$cidvar))
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',array('neq'=>0));
        $collection1 = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',array('eq'=>$cidvar))
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',array('neq'=>0));
        $collection2= Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',array('eq'=>$cidvar))
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',array('neq'=>0));
        $collection3 = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',array('eq'=>$cidvar))
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',array('neq'=>0));
        $first_day_of_week = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Last Monday', time()));
        $last_day_of_week = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Next Sunday', time()));
        $month=$collection1->addFieldToFilter('cleared_at', array('datetime' => true,'from' =>  date('Y-m').'-01 00:00:00','to' =>  date('Y-m').'-31 23:59:59'));
        $week=$collection2->addFieldToFilter('cleared_at', array('datetime' => true,'from' =>  $first_day_of_week.' 00:00:00','to' =>  $last_day_of_week.' 23:59:59'));
        $day=$collection3->addFieldToFilter('cleared_at', array('datetime' => true,'from' =>  date('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00','to' =>  date('Y-m-d').' 23:59:59'));
        $sale=0;

        $data1['year']=$sale;
        $sale1=0;
        foreach($day as $record1) {
            $sale1=$sale1+$record1->getactualparterprocost();
        }
        $data1['day']=$sale1;
        $sale2=0;
        foreach($month as $record2) {
            $sale2=$sale2+$record2->getactualparterprocost();
        }
        $data1['month']=$sale2;
        $sale3=0;
        foreach($week as $record3) {
            $sale3=$sale3+$record3->getactualparterprocost();
        }
        $data1['week']=$sale3;
        $temp=0;
        foreach ($collection as $record) {
            $temp = $temp+$record->getactualparterprocost();
        }
        $data1['totalamount']=$temp;
        return $data1;
    }
    public function getMonthlysale(){
        $customerid = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();
        $data=array();  
        $curryear = date('Y');
        for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++){
            $date1=$curryear."-".$i."-01 00:00:00";
            $date2=$curryear."-".$i."-31 23:59:59";
            $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
            $collection=$collection->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',array('eq'=>$customerid));
            $collection=$collection->addFieldToFilter('cleared_at', array('datetime' =>true,'from' =>  $date1,'to' =>  $date2));
            $sum=array();
            $temp=0;
            foreach ($collection as $record) {
                $temp = $temp+$record->getactualparterprocost();
            }
            $baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
            $currentCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
            $price = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($temp, $baseCurrencyCode, $currentCurrencyCode);
            $data[$i]=$price;
        }
        return json_encode($data);
    }
    public function getOrderdetails(){
        $customerid = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',array('eq'=>$customerid))->setOrder('autoid','DESC');
        $userorder=array();
        $gropoid=array();
        $groporderid=array();
        $productname=array();
        $i=0; 
        foreach ($collection as $record) {
        $i++;
            if($i<=5){
                if(count($gropoid) && $record->getmagerealorderid()==$gropoid[$i-1]){
                    $i--;
                    $productid=$productid.",".$record->getmageproid();
                    $productname=$productname.",".$record->getmageproname()." X ".$record->getmagequantity();
                    $pprice=$pprice+$record->getactualparterprocost();
                    $userorder[$i]=array('mageproid'=>$productid,
                                            'mageorderid'=>$record->getmageorderid(),
                                            'magerealorderid'=>$record->getmagerealorderid(),
                                            'mageproname'=>$productname,
                                            'actualparterprocost'=>$pprice,
                                            'cleared_at'=>$record->getcleared_at()
                                            );          
                }
                else{
                    $productname=$record->getmageproname()." X ".$record->getmagequantity();
                    $productid=$record->getmageproid();
                    $pprice=$record->getactualparterprocost();
                    $groporderid[$i]=$record->getmageorderid();
                    $gropoid[$i]=$record->getmagerealorderid();
                    $userorder[$i]=array('mageproid'=>$record->getmageproid(),
                                        'mageorderid'=>$record->getmageorderid(),
                                        'magerealorderid'=>$record->getmagerealorderid(),
                                        'mageproname'=>$productname,
                                        'actualparterprocost'=>$pprice,
                                        'cleared_at'=>$record->getcleared_at()
                                        );          
                }   
            }
        }
    return $userorder;  
    }
    public function getPaymentDetailById(){
        $customerid = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getCollection();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('mageuserid',array('eq'=>$customerid));
        foreach($collection as $row){
            $paymentsource=$row->getPaymentsource();
        }
        return $paymentsource;
    }

    public function getpronamebyorder($mageorderid){
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $name='';
        $_collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
        $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$mageorderid); 
        $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',$customerid);   
        foreach($_collection as $res){
            $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($res['mageproid']);
            /*$name = $name."<p style='float:left;'><a href='".Mage::getUrl($products->getUrlPath())."' target='blank'>".$res['mageproname']."</a> X ".intval($res['magequantity'])."&nbsp;</p>";*/

             $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($res['mageproid']);
                /* Custom Code */
               /*Restrict Character length*/
                $orderdproname = $res['mageproname'];
                $orderdproname_length = strlen($orderdproname);

                if ($orderdproname_length >25){
                    $orderdproname = substr($orderdproname,0,25)."..";
                }
                else{
                    $orderdproname = $res['mageproname'];
                }

                $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                $readconnection = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_read');
                $allrecord = $readconnection->select()->from(array('mpassignproduct'=>'marketplace_assignproduct'))->where('mpassignproduct.mpassignproduct_id=?', $res['mpassignproduct_id']);
                $mpassignproduct =$readconnection->fetchAll($allrecord);     
                if(count($mpassignproduct)) {
                 foreach($mpassignproduct as $assignproduct)
                   {   $name = $name."<div class='my-order-history-details'><div class='my-order-history-proname'><a href='".Mage::getUrl($products->getUrlPath())."' target='blank'>".$orderdproname."</a></div> <div class='my-order-history-sku'><strong>".$assignproduct['sku']." </strong></div> <div class='my-order-history-qty'><span>".intval($res['magequantity'])."</span></div>&nbsp;</div>";

                   }
                    } else {
                     $name = $name."<div class='my-order-history-details'><div class='my-order-history-proname'><a href='".Mage::getUrl($products->getUrlPath())."' target='blank'>".$orderdproname."</a></div> <div class='my-order-history-sku'><strong>".$products->getSku()." </strong></div> <div class='my-order-history-qty'><span>".intval($res['magequantity'])."</span></div>&nbsp;</div>";
                      }


                }
                    /* Custom Code */
        return $name;       
    }

    public function getPricebyorder($mageorderid){
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $_collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
        $_collection->getSelect()
                    ->where('mageproownerid ='.$customerid)
                    ->columns('SUM(actualparterprocost) AS qty')
                    ->group('mageorderid');     
        foreach($_collection as $coll){
            if($coll->getMageorderid() == $mageorderid){
                return $coll->getQty();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: this function is calculate the commission of the seller. paste the view code maybe helpfull

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: `$total_sale` where are you setting this value in view?

Comment: Check now i updated view file

Comment: check this table and post column. `marketplace/saleperpartner`

Comment: I updated table sturcture

Comment: sorry i did not find any relation between order and your lifetime sales table.

Comment: Yes but can we decrease total sale if status is rto

Comment: i think the order will be added to lifetime sale after the order status is complete that my assumption. check it if it is true you are no need of that and if it is directly adding then you have to find where it is adding and remove from there.

Comment: No i din't get ????

Comment: check on which event it is adding the sales in seller account.

Comment: i think this that event <sales_order_save_commit_after>
                <observers>
                    <Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
                        <class>Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>commissionCalculationOnComplete</method>
                    </Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_commit_after> right??

Comment: <sales_order_invoice_save_after>
    <observers>
     <Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
      <class>Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer</class>
      <method>checkInvoiceSubmit</method>
     </Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
    </observers>
   </sales_order_invoice_save_after>

Comment: yes it is calculating on `commissionCalculationOnComplete` complete i think it is not adding the other status.

Comment: yes what will do public function commissionCalculationOnComplete($observer){
     $order = $observer->getOrder();
     if($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE){
      Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCommsionCalculation($order);
     }
 }

Comment: no need of that because order status in rto is not adding in seller sales..

Comment: ok now what will do for that

Comment: no need of doing anything leave this because the order with `rto` is not added to seller sales. so you cannot put check on that..

Comment: sorry i can't get this

Comment: if the order status in `rto` is not adding in sales of seller.

Comment: Let us assume i orderd 1 product that time seller dashboard it shows Today: amount Week : amount : Month : amount if i click rto is still same it not reduce that's the problem

Comment: now this is different is there is life time have the same problem?

Comment: In seller dashboard this thing only display not lifetime sale\

Comment: paste that code not life time sale code..

Comment: this function `getDateDetail`

Comment: It already there check saleslist.php in my question

Comment: i answer you after an hour..

Comment: Sorry i didn't get

Comment: i already award to you on that day itself

Comment: Share that question url

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99994/magento-custom-order/100728#100728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add state condition like that on each collection.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
                                        ->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',array('eq'=>$cidvar))
                                        ->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',array('neq'=>0));
            $collection->getSelect()->join(array('order' => 'sales_flat_order'), 'main_table.mageorderid=order.entity_id and order.state!="rto"',
                    array('order.entity_id'));
```

Comment: Really Thanks bro how it works. How it subtract?

Comment: this condition `and order.state!="rto"` for subtract  the `rto`

Comment: which doubt you have in mind?

Comment: Editing core file is bad practice but i try to create same in local location but it not affacting

Comment: Let us assume this file app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Order/Collection.php

Comment: app/code/local/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Order/Collection.php  this will work for you. delete the cache to make sure

Comment: Ok bro i will try once again all block, model helper also same right

Comment: yes block,model,helper  ..........

Comment: Did you face thease problem http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101345/magento-product-collection-less-then-the-original-price