# Magento Product Collection less then the Original price

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection, special-price

How to get Special price less or not

```
  <?php 

$categoryIds = array(469);//category id

$todayDate = date('m/d/y');
        $tomorrow = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('y'));
        $tomorrowDate = date('m/d/y', $tomorrow);

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                             ->getCollection()
                             ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                             ->addMinimalPrice()->addFinalPrice()
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                             ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds))
                             ->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))

                             ->addFinalPrice()

                   ->getSelect()
                   ->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price')


                             ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                                0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $tomorrowDate))
                                ), 'left')




?>
```

I want to display if special price less then the original price how to get that ?

Comment: you want to get special price product collection?

Comment: Yes if product have special price and less then the original price

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    $categoryIds = array(469);//category id



    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')

->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryIds));
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $products->getAllIds()));;
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect(array(
                                   'image',
                                   'name',
                                   'short_description'
                   ))
                   ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', array(
                               Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                               Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                   )) 
                   ->addFinalPrice()

                   ->getSelect()
                   ->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price')


                   print_r($_productCollection->getAllIds());
```

Comment: I tried previousley

Comment: Check my updated question anythin wrong

Comment: try update my updated and feedback me.

Comment: No it's not working after that i echo $collection->count() but it didn't display anything

Comment: i think it's not move after this

Comment: echo count($collection); try that and also print_r($collection->getAllIds()); for check this

Comment: I already try it not display anything

Comment: Previously it display after add this code it's not display

Comment: With out that code i got Array ( [0] => 17572 ) 1

Comment: it is correct data?

Comment: After remove this  ->getSelect()
                   ->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price'); then only it display

Comment: try this added answer and feedback me..

Comment: Now also same not working

Comment: not echo anything

Comment: try this code it is tested and working ...

Comment: `print_r($products->getAllIds());` check what output of this?

Comment: it return Array ( )

Comment: check the category have product..

Comment: yes it have 1 product

Comment: check the visibility and other thing.. because i test this code and it is working try with any other category and make sure the category in array.

Comment: Other id's working this only not working

Comment: then it is a product issue... not the code issue..

Comment: Ok can you please update the code

Comment: this is  updated code i tried and paste it there...

Comment: Ok i will check it

Comment: is it correct  ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)->setOrder('price', 'DESC')

Comment: visibility filter is there just set order in last

Comment: Actually i want to display highest special price first so iused this ->setOrder('special_price', 'ASC')

Comment: add ->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price')->setOrder('special_price', 'ASC')

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: `->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price')->setOrder('price_index.final_price', 'ASC')` try that

Comment: ->setOrder('price', 'ASC') it's working fine thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add  `->addMinimalPrice()->addFinalPrice()` to collection for getting  price.

Comment: Where i can add this under collection

Answer (score 1):

A good thing to do is to use the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer` class to prepare your product collections. Increases performance (as opposed to just use a wildcard in `addAttributeToSelect`) and fully prepares your collection, the same way it happens in generic category product listings.

So for example, you'd do something like this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')
    ->setCurrentCategory(469)
    ->getProductCollection();
```

As far as I know (haven't tested this right now), it should automatically apply the special price and everything you'd need to create a product listing. Doing it yourself is asking for trouble.

Comment: it will display all product under this category there is no filtered

Comment: @Kothari you can still add your own filters to it. $products is a collection